# Table inside a loop

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have one table in loop which come under li:

```
<?php
 for($i=1;$i<=$tc;$i++)
 {
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  ?>
  <li style="list-style:none; margin-left:-20px">
  <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
 <td class="hline" style="width:267px"><?php  echo $row['tit'] .",". $row['name'] ?></td>
<td class="vline" style="width:1px">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="hline" style="width:100px"><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

The output comes like this:

[alt text http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/4153/67396040.gif](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/4153/67396040.gif)

- I can't put table outside the loop, due to `<li>` sorting

Comment: i really can't find out what you wanna do! please revise the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can't use table outside the loop then i think best option will be use of

```
     <div>
```

statement

for example

```
   <div class="q-s na">
     <div class="st" style="margin-right:10px; width:150px">
        <div class="m-c"><?php  echo $row['tit'] .",". $row['name'] ?></div>
    </div>
```

this will be same as you one

```
      <td>
```

you can define style according to your requirements.

for example

```
        <style>
    .q-s{overflow:hidden;width:664px;float:left; 
         padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:2px; height:25px}

      .na .st{ float:left;}
   .na .m-c {border-bottom:1px dotted #999; padding-bottom:10px; height:15px}
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

> i can't put table outside the loop.

Why not? This is where it belongs. After all, you (logically) produce *one* table, not many of them. No need for the list item, either.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to put the table outside of the loop, you should probably just use  tags rather than creating tables, as you're defeating the purpose of even having a table by making each table a single row and trying to stack them.

Another thing to note if you are going to stick with tables:

If you're hard-coding the table width AND all of the table cell (column) widths, it may cause unexpected issues when they don't add up:

Table width = 600px

Cells = 267 + 1 + 100 = 368px